# Impresión de múltiples etiquetas en una sola página - JasperReoport

Tags: jasper-reports, jasper

Tengo un report principal en el que quiero imprimir en toda la pagina una etiqueta con un nombre de usuario, este siempre será el mismo
Tal que quede de la siguiente manera pero toda la página:

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He conseguido imprimir de forma horizontal editando las propiedades avanzadas del report, pero necesito hacerlo en toda la página.

Un saludo

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer si te sirve como solución es hacer la misma consulta 2 veces, de esta forma te imprime el mismo reporte 2 veces

Comment: El a4 de las etiquetas consta de 4 x 17, sería necesario una sola consulta y que duplicara el subreport n veces para cubrir cada hueco, ¿sería posible?

Comment: Como presentas hay dos formas, la primera es añadiendo código al reporte, el cuál duplicaría. O añadiendo dos veces el subreporte al reporte que mencionas

Comment: He encontrado una forma, en las propiedades avanzadas del report: Page Colums, modificando esas propiedades duplica la etiqueta, pero solo en horizontal, ¿se podría hacer en vertical también?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que nos rellene automáticamente con solo un campo de texto, la query que tengamos en el informe debe repetir los valores tantas veces como necesitemos.
En este caso yo necesitaba rellenar 4 columnas por 17 filas.
Para ello la query quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT A.nombreUsuario
(U.nombre FROM USUARIO U 
U.id = 4) A,
(SELECT ROWNUM n
FROM ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE ROWNUM <= 68) B;
```

De esta forma tenemos el valor que deseamos imprimir las veces que necesitamos.
A parte de la query, en las propiedades avanzadas del informe necesitamos editar el Page Colums para que imprima en horizontal y con el numero de columnas que queremos, su tamaño y el espacio entre ellas.